# Flattening Tool?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

Is it in any way possible to take multiple verticies, ( on top of eachother, along the Z Axis ) and make them completely linear? Like, they are a little out of place, and i want them to be straight as a line on Z Axis. Help?

Comment: Select both of the vertices, press 'S' to scale then 'Z' and then '0'. Should align then perfectly.

Comment: This way they all end up the exact same spot. i want to keep the same distance between them

Comment: you have to _exclude_ the Z axis, so press S to scale, then shift-Z then zero, they will get the same X and Y. The chosen pivot mode counts.

Comment: Thanks man, Helps alot! How do i accept your answer??